# post some inputs that is inside an iframe,that is inside a form,as a whole form

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

Hi guys I have two questions, first, can I post inputs inside an iframe that is inside a form, as a part of the parent form?

second, I am rendering a google map with markers, based on a search, inside an iframe that ist loaded inside a form.

I need to get values of the markers, by drag n drop, out of the iframe, into the parent form.
I could do this without drag n drop with jquery, but I want user friendly interface(I am already using jQuerys Draggable and Droppable).
thanks in advance

Comment: If the iframe is in the same domain as the parent window it's possible. Might have some problems with some browsers. Do you have a specific code you want to share? what did not work for you?

Comment: "If the iframe is in the same domain" then why are you using an iframe at all?

Comment: I'm using iframe to load google map(performance issue),I found out that I can select the parent elements of iframe, from within iframe using jquery : $('$myElement' , window.parent.document); and then I moved every thing I needed to the parent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I did was, I just moved the inputs I needed filled, to my main window(parent) and used a function in the parent to handle generated data in the iframe using:

```
window.parent.myfunction(data);
```

whenever I needed to pass data from scripts in iframe to parent window, I did the above.

cheers